# JUnit test asking for context?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, junit

I am creating a unit test for this boolean method. Its purpose is to return a boolean value if it inserts a new row in the database. (Boolean value is used for error handling). This method is a part of my "DBHelper" class.

```
    public Boolean insertBorrowerDetails(String FirstName, String LastName, String NickName, String PhoneNumber)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues BorrowerContentValues = new ContentValues();
    BorrowerContentValues.put("FirstName",FirstName);
    BorrowerContentValues.put("LastName",LastName);
    BorrowerContentValues.put("NickName",NickName);
    BorrowerContentValues.put("PhoneNumber",PhoneNumber);
    long InsertBorrowerResult = db.insert("Borrowers",null, BorrowerContentValues);
    if (InsertBorrowerResult==-1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the unit test I've attempted to create for the method.

```
       @Test
        public void insertBorrowerDetailsTest() {
        String FirstName = "John";
        String LastName = "Doe";
        String NickName = "";
        String PhoneNumber = "0467823618";
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(); Here its asking me for context?? Not sure why..
        Boolean result = db.insertBorrowerDetails(FirstName,LastName,NickName,PhoneNumber);
        assertEquals(result,false);
        }
```

This is my first unit test so I'm not particularly sure why its asking me for the context. I have also tried to call the insertBorrowerDetails method without initialising the DBHelper class but the method is non-static so it seems I cant just inherit the method. Any idea how I could actually perform a unit test on this method?

Comment: have you checked your DBHelper constructor? Can you post the actual message?

Comment: @Stultuske actually thats a good point, am I able to just remove the context parameters from the constructor?

Comment: yes, of course. Might that cause problems if you do so? yes, of course.